# OpenStreetMap server API on my own server

Tags: openstreetmap

I followed this tutorial to make own OpenStreetMap server: http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/

Now I would like to use OSM API (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6) to read the map. I dont need rendering tiles but to read nodes/ways over REST API.

There is running Apache on my OSM server so I believe I should put it there.

Is API part of Mapnik or should I download some additional software? Or is API specific to main OSM server only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This API is specific to OSM, Mapnik is not involved. You can read more about it at the [API page in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API). The API implementation is contained in the [Rails port](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rails_port) which is hosted on the [openstreetmap-website github project](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website).

Note that this API is primarily designed for editing purposes and not for bulk queries. Depending on your use case it might be a better idea to set up the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) on your server. This API is usually faster and features a complex [query language](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) with many nice features not contained in the main API.